# Find Number in Array (two-digit Number)

Tags: javascript, arrays, split, find, include

I try to find the Number 7 in an Array and return `true`
(Doesn´t matter if it´s `7`,  `47` or `507`)

The Array: `[17, 23, 9, 590]`

I tried to use `arr.includes(7)` but this just returns the Number `7`.
(So it returns `false` in this case because there is no `7` in the Array - only `17`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the comparison `number === 7`, you should compare each digit instead.

You can use the function `Array.prototype.some`, and the function `String.prototype.includes` to check for a specific digit/char.

*This approach finds the number `7` over each number's digit.*

```js
console.log([17, 23, 9, 590].some(n => String(n).includes(7)))
```

Answer (score 1):

You could join the numbers and look if `7` is included.

```js
var data = [17, 23, 9, 590],
    has7 = data.join('').includes(7);

console.log(has7);
```

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't you mod the number by 10 and then look for 7?

```js
const findByLeastSigFig = (arr, n) => arr.find(x => x % 10 === n);

console.log(findByLeastSigFig([17, 23, 9, 590], 7));
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the 7 is only valid in the last position you could use the rest of division by 10

```js
const elements = [7, 9, 17, 23, 57, 407, 590];
const result = elements.filter(element => element % 10 === 7)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: Hmm yes, but 7 is not always at the end, but thank you very much any way!

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one correct answer to this problem. One of the simplest and most intuitive ones (without compromising on performance) is to use [`Array.prototype.toString()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/toString) which joins the array and returns one string containing each array element separated by commas. `[17, 23, 9, 590].toString()` returns the string `"17,23,9,590"` and then look for the index of 7 using [`String.prototype.indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/indexOf) which returns the 0-based index of the serach value or -1 if not found.

To sum it up in one line:

```js
console.log([17, 23, 9, 590].toString().indexOf(7) != -1);
```

Comment: Could you edit your answer to provide a little bit more of context to your suggestion?

Comment: Thank you for answering a question. While your answer looks correct, it would be great if you could not just answer with a line of code, but explain why this answer works as well. This will help the OP understand what you write, but also understand whether there might be some cases not covered by what you suggest.